# Context for an inherited service

Tags: android, fileobserver

Maybe my question is a bit dumb but I searched how to do this and I figured it out how can I solve this and I can't.

I'm trying to create a Notification from a service when an event occur with the NotificationCompat class.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                     .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                                     .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
```

The problem is that object "this" is a FileObserver class and I don't know how to get context from it to initialize notifications. To sum up, Can I get context inside that event listener?

```
public abstract class DBAbstractService extends Service {
    .....
}

public class FileModificationService extends DBAbstractService {

    public FileModificationService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
       ......
       ......
       public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
            if((FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE & event) != 0){
                if(file.substring(0,3).equals("RVE")) {
                    try {
                         if (aux[2].equals("D")){
                                Log.i("INFO:", "Modificación no realizada");

                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                                                .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
            //More code
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: try `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Oh that worked thank you very much I knew that was a silly question. Should I delete this dumb question?

Comment: yes. Please delete it.

Comment: I cant because it has answer :(

Comment: Then Un select the answer and delete.

Comment: I can't either. I have flagged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                     .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                                     .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
```

inside `onEvent` method hence `this` will not point to `Service` object 
so you have to write

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                         .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                                         .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), that is why you reference it by `this` keyword to pass the required `Context` object, and you may reference it from an inner class by typing `FileModificationService.this` and that would accomplish the task.